# Everyone who loves all animals is loved by someone -- logic interpretation

Tags: logic

The common example of a sentence written in first order logic is " Everyone who loves all animals is loved by someone." In first order logic, it is written as:

$$
\forall x [\forall y \ \ Animal(y) \implies Loves(x,y)] \implies [\exists y \ \ Loves(y,x)]
$$

Doesn't the first part of this state that "For all animals, then all x loves all animals?" If so, then that is not what the original sentence stated because the original sentence never says that there is someone who loves all animals. Could someone help me understand this? #Edit: I think I understand this particular part now -- it is a premise used for the second implication.

In addition, if I want to represent everyone loves all animals, could that be represented as:

$$
\forall x \forall y \ \ Animal(y) \land Loves(x,y)
$$

So it seems above sentence can be represented as 
$$
\forall x \forall y \ \ Animal(y) \land Loves(x,y) \implies \exists y \ \  Loves(y,x)
$$
But this is not equivalent to the former logic.

Comment: Well, humans are animals, so . . .

Comment: @Shaun Yes, but I don't see why that is relevant?

Comment: It isn't particularly relevant. You're right to point that out.

Comment: The formula $\forall x\forall y (Animal(y)\land Loves(x,y))$ says "everything is an animal that is loved by everyone." The formula you want is $\forall x\forall y (Animal(y)\implies Loves(x,y))$.  If the term "everyone" is intended to mean *Humans* only, then perhaps you need to say $\forall x\forall y((Human(x)\land Animal(y))\implies Loves(x,y))$. (Note, I've added some extra parentheses to make unambiguous the range of the qualifiers.)

Comment: @BarryCipra I think I understand the first part now. However, I don't understand the logic for your second part. Isn't the premise saying that all x are humans and all y are animals?

Comment: @David, the assertion "$(Human(x)\land Animal(y))\implies Loves(x,y)$" says "If $x$ is a Human and $y$ is an Animal, then $x$ Loves $y$."

Comment: @BarryCipra Right, but if you put the $\forall x \forall y$ before the premise, doesn't it say "If all x are human and all y are Animal, then..."? Actually, perhaps I should try to understand this first, is there a difference between $\forall x \forall y (Animal(y) \land Loves(x,y))$ and $\forall x \forall y Animal(y) \land Loves(x,y)?$

Comment: @David, no, you need to refresh your understanding of how qualifiers work in logical assertions.  The "for all"s apply to the entire assertion "If $x$ is a Human and $y$ is an Animal, then $x$ Loves $y$," not just to the first portion.

Comment: @BarryCipra Does "no" refer to the first or second question? I think I'm going to go back to the basics. Do you have a reference you can suggest?

Comment: @David, sorry, the "no" mainly referred to the first question. As for the second, I'm not sure what the conventions are, but I encourage the use of parentheses to make it absolutely clear that the "for all"s pertain to the entire formula. And sorry, no, I don't have a reference to suggest, at least not one that I know is useful. Maybe someone else does.

Comment: Ah I see. So when I originally wrote the $\forall x \forall y(Animal(y) \land Animal(x))$, I was asking if this is saying that "everyone loves all animals." But it doesn't seem to be saying that after seeing your comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105887/discussion-between-david-and-barry-cipra).